# JQuery jVal plugin running out of space on form

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I am using the JQuery plugin jVal.   This plugin validates user input.   If the user makes an error the input box is turned red and a fly out message says what is wrong.   This works great for forms where there is one Label and one input per visual row.    This falls apart when you have multiple labels and inputs per row.   IE the fly out error gets confused with the underlying information.   Is there a way to have just a * next to the field having the error, then display a summary of the all field errors in a different DIV.  I am open to other JQuery plugins that would give me validation and the presentation I am after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery [validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) allows you to customize it's error messages -- plain text, no fly-outs.  The default messages can also be changed as well -- either in the backend code or by configuration (using the messages option).